# Ember, There is no route named contact error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm a newbie to Ember. I used latest version **2.6.2**. I was struggling with a route. When I go to contacts page I got an error like this **Error: There is no route named contact**.

My app/route.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('contacts', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:contact_id' });
  });
});
```

My app/routes/contacts/index.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('contact');
  }
});
```

My app/templates/contacts/index.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |contact|}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to 'contact' contact}}
      {{contact.lastName}},
      {{contact.firstName}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No contacts found.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My app/models/contact.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')   
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that error if `link-to` is linking to a route that is not found in your routes.

You have two named routes in `router.js` 1. `contacts` 2. `contacts.show`

Change your `app/templates/contacts/index.hbs` file.

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |contact|}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to 'contacts.show' contact}}
        {{contact.lastName}},
        {{contact.firstName}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No contacts found.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```